# Store dask dataframe to CSV with "bucket-owner-full-control" ACL

Tags: dask

I need to store dask dataframe to CSV on S3 with a *bucket-owner-full-control* in order to give full access to the bucket owner. Is there a way to do it?

Below code doesn't achieve it:

```
storage_opts = {'s3_additional_kwargs':
                                {'ACL': 'bucket-owner-full-control'}}
dataframe.to_csv(url, storage_options=storage_opts, **self.kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right command, but there was a bug, because there were multiple places in which the ACL could be defined. The fix is awaiting testing at:
https://github.com/dask/s3fs/pull/105

Comment: Now merged - available in s3fs master.