# Writing into someone else's s3 bucket but no one can read it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing into someone else's s3 bucket but no one can read it.
How do I make it so that the owner of the s3 bucket can read what im writing into the bucket? Is this something they would have to change on their end since they are the owner or is this something I can change on my end?

I dont see the Bucket on my Amazon S3 buckets list because I am not the owner. Therefore, I cannot change the permissions there (or can I change the settings on an invisible bucket?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading to an Amazon S3 bucket that belongs to a different account, use `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control`. This will 'handover' ownership of the object to the other account.

This is a very strange behaviour of Amazon S3 that they have now corrected by offering the ability to  **disable ACLs and enforce the Bucket owner**. If the owner of the bucket configures this setting, then it will work as expected (without needing to specify the ACL on upload).

See: [Controlling ownership of objects and disabling ACLs for your bucket - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html)

Comment: Thank you John. Where in my code do i enter `ACL=bucket-owner-full-control`? In CMD, or in my notebook, etc?

Comment: It would be provided when uploading the object. How are you writing the object to the "other person's" bucket?

Comment: I am running a full .py file that we are both editing. It automatically pulls from a datasource and writes into their S3 bucket. I made my edits and ran the file, but he cannot access the output.

Comment: What is the command that you are using to upload the file to S3?

Comment: I believe it is: `df.to_csv(f"s3://{self.bucket}/{prefix}/{self.ts}/{keycontent}.csv", index = False)`

Comment: Ah! It's using dataframes. This seems to address that question: [Store dask dataframe to CSV with "bucket-owner-full-control" ACL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980362/store-dask-dataframe-to-csv-with-bucket-owner-full-control-acl)

Comment: Awesome rerunning now, will let u know if it works, looks promising! Thank you!